# How to represent some logical propositions

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I logically represent the following propositions:

1. At most one of $p$,$q$,$r$.
2. Only one of $p$, $q$, $r$.

My solutions:

1. ($p$ and ~($q$ or $r$)) or ($q$ and ~($p$ or $r$)) or ($r$ and ~( $p$ or $q$)).
2. ($p$ and ~($q$ and $r$)) or ($q$ and ~($p$ and $r$)) or ($r$ and ~($p$ and $q$)).

Comment: For 1., you also need to allow for none of them being true, so add a clause "or $(\neg p \land \neg q \land \neg r)$".

Answer (score 2):

For (1), "at most one of" a set means 1 or fewer from the set. Your solution for (1) rules out 2 or more of $p,q,r$, which is good, but you need to think about numbers smaller than 1 :-).

For (2), ($p$ and ~($q$ and $r$)) is true if $p$ is true and $q$ is true and $r$ is false, so it doesn't do what you want.  Hint: your original answer for (1) seems to work for (2)!

Answer (score 1):

The correct answers are the following ($\land$ stands for "and", $\lor$ stands for "or"):

1. (~$p$ $\lor$ ~($q$ $\lor$ $r$)) $\land$ (~$q$ $\lor$ ~($p$ $\lor$ $r$)) $\land$ (~$r$ $\lor$ ~($p$ $\lor$ $q$))
2. ($p$ $\land$ ~($q$ $\lor$ $r$)) $\lor$ ($q$ $\land$ ~($p$ $\lor$ $r$)) $\lor$ ($r$ $\land$ ~( $p$ $\lor$ $q$)).

Note that your original answer for (1) is actually the good answer for (2).

You can check the soundness of my answers looking at the following truth table, in particular rows 4, 6-8 for question (1), and rows 4, 6-7 for question (2):

$
\begin{array}{ccc|cccccc}
\quad p & \quad q & \quad r \quad & \ \sim\!p & \sim\!(q \lor r) &\sim\!q & \sim\!(p \lor r) & \sim\!r & \sim\!(p \lor q) \\
\quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{T} \quad & \quad \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{F} \quad & \quad \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{T} \quad & \quad \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{F} \quad & \quad \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{T} \quad & \quad \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{T} & \quad \mathtt{F} \quad & \quad \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} \\
\quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{T} \quad & \quad \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{F} & \mathtt{T} \\
\quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{F} & \quad \mathtt{F} \quad & \quad \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} & \mathtt{T} \\
\end{array}
$

Comment: To me it's hard to explain .....

Answer (score 1):

[XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) might also come handy for (2) as

$$p \oplus q \oplus r$$

will be true if, and only if, an odd number of variables are true. But then,

$$(p \oplus q \oplus r) \land \lnot (p \land q \land r)$$

will be true if, and only if, exactly one of them is true.

Once you have solved (2), (1) follows immediately as it's equivalent to

$$((p \oplus q \oplus r) \land \lnot (p \land q \land r)) \lor \lnot (p \lor q \lor r)$$

i.e., "exactly one is true OR none is true".

Comment: I think it will be better  if we put it in the form p(+) ( q (+) r) ...

Comment: Well, that's pretty much just a matter of readability, since XOR is associative (just as you don't usually write $x+(y+z)$ but $x+y+z$)